# Como comparar nome de duas imagens no Android Studio

Tags: android, imagem, imageview

Tendo um

```
imagem = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewId);
```

Como faço para saber se a imagem atual tem o nome x ou y?

Tentei algumas formas , com o equals e tal, mas não funcionou....

```
if (imagem.equals("nome")){...
```

Comment: Mas a ideia é comparar imagens ? Ela foi atribuida diretamente no layout?

Comment: A imagem será setada dinamicamente. Se a escolhida for X quero fazer uma ação...

Comment: O que exatamente você está tentando fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Suponho que quando diz "nome da imagem" se está a referir ao ID atribuído por `android:id` ou `setId()`, neste caso `R.id.imageViewId`.

Se assim é, use o método `imagem.getId()` para obter o ID que lhe foi atribuído:

```
if (imagem.getId() == R.id.imageViewId){...
```

Comment: Porque não o `equals()` ?

Comment: @RBZ `equals()`, neste caso, serve para verificar se são a mesma instância.